# Swift framework with Objective-C Static library included

Tags: swift, import, module, frameworks, static-libraries

I need to create a framework in `swift`, that will internally use a `static library`. It would be great if this library was only visible internally in this framework. I have added all the files of this `library` to the `framework`, and I have created a `module.modulemap` file. This file looks like this:

```
framework module MySDK {
    umbrella header "MySDK.h"
    export *
}

module BluFi {
    header "/Users/homedudycz/Documents/Developer/MyApp/MySDK/blufiprotocol/DH_AES.h"
    export *
}
```

And I can now use objects from this `static library` inside my `framework`, but there is a problem. When I try to import my `framework` in some `app` I get an error: `Missing required module 'BluFi'`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to import this `static` library inside my `framework` internally?

I have also created a sample project with libraries that I need added in this SDK. Please take a look, and please update path in module.modulemap - I don't know how to make it relative to SDK path :/

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnh7y7zr63zillv/TestApp.zip?dl=1